# unique algorithm with move iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator, c++14

Is it permittable to use `std::unique` with iterators created by means of `std::make_move_iterator` function? I tried [the following](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8257229d75ef5f69), and got success:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <iterator>

#include <cstdlib>

struct A
{

    A() : i(std::numeric_limits< double >::quiet_NaN()) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
    A(double ii) : i(ii) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
    A(A const & a) : i(a.i) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
    A(A && a) : i(std::move(a.i)) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; a.i = std::numeric_limits< double >::quiet_NaN(); }
    A & operator = (A const & a) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; i = a.i; return *this; }
    A & operator = (A && a) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; i = std::move(a.i); a.i = std::numeric_limits< double >::quiet_NaN(); return *this; }
    bool operator < (A const & a) const { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; return (i < a.i); }
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wfloat-equal"
    bool operator == (A const & a) const { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; return (i == a.i); }
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

    friend
    std::ostream &
    operator << (std::ostream & o, A const & a)
    {
        return o << a.i;
    }

private :

    double i;

};

int
main()
{
    std::vector< A > v{1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 7.0};
    std::cout << "v constructed\n\n\n\n";
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    auto const end = std::unique(std::make_move_iterator(v.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(v.end())).base();
    std::copy(v.begin(), end, std::ostream_iterator< A >(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But maybe is it implementation-dependent success?

And what regarding other algorithms from `<numeric>` and `<algorithm>`?

Comment: `std::unique` moves anyway, so I don't see what you gain from it.

Comment: @T.C. What do you mean? `std::unique` copy-assigning [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) in section "Possible implementation".

Comment: That's not a good implementation. Real libraries [move](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/198b772ffc2f41ba).

Comment: @T.C. Does they move mandatory?

Comment: It must support all `MoveAssignable` types, so it's actually more work for the library implementer to not move.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program is guaranteed to work by the standard.
`std::unique` requires forward iterators.  The easiest way to show up that move iterators satisfy that requirement is to inspect the `iterator_category` typedef of `move_iterator`:

```
typedef typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category iterator_category;
```

As you can see, the iterator category of the underlying iterator type is directly adapted. In fact, the behavior of move iterators is almost equivalent to their underlying ones, [move.iterators]/1:

> Class template `move_iterator` is an iterator adaptor with the same
>   behavior as the underlying iterator except that its indirection
>   operator implicitly converts the value returned by the underlying
>   iterator’s indirection operator to an rvalue reference.

There are no other noteworthy requirements: Clearly `vector<>::iterator` is an input iterator (as required by [move.iter.requirements]). The only relevant requirement imposed by `unique` itself is

> The type of `*first` shall satisfy the `MoveAssignable` requirements
>   (Table 22).

... which is straightforwardly met.

Note that using move iterators should not bring any advantage over normal ones. Internally the duplicate elements are move-assigned (hence the `MoveAssignable` requirement), so returning an rvalue reference from `operator*` is superfluous.

Comment: No, internally `std::unique` must use move assignment directly. Using `swap` would require `MoveConstructible` as well.

Comment: @T.C. Seems to be correct. Are the elements actually swapped then, or are the ones after the returned new end in a moved-from state?

Comment: @T.C. libstdc++ seems to do `*++__dest = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(*__first)`, which indicates that the latter is true.

Comment: `remove` has a note that says the remainder has valid but unspecified state. `unique` doesn't, but should still be the case.

Comment: @Orient The requirement is [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable).

Comment: `unique` also requires a forward iterator, but that requirement is also obviously met.